# Which Zelda game came out after Skyward Sword?

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series

I searched in google but did not get any good results. Do you know the name of the next Legend of Zelda game after Skyward Sword?

Comment: Questions about **unreleased** or illegal content are off topic on Arqade. We only support questions about games available to the general public through legitimate means.

Comment: There were actually two Legend of Zelda games released between Twilight Princess and Skyward Sword: Phantom Hourglass and Spirit Tracks, both of which were released for the Nintendo DS.

Comment: This is on hold as off-topic because it's about unreleased content, but the game after Skyward Sword has already been released (and no more are being released for the Wii).

Comment: @Brian The question being asked is also rather unclear.  It's hard to tell whether he's asking which game comes *after* Twilight Princess, chronologically or in-canon, or if he's asking what the name of the next Legend of Zelda game is going to be.  I'm leaning towards the latter interpretation.  If it's clarified to mean one of the former, I'll vote to reopen, but I still don't think it's a good question; we're not a wiki site that stores all information about all games.

Comment: @Frank I determined that he wasn't asking about chronology because he said that Twilight Princess was the last one. Twilight Princess is neither chronologically before Skyward Sword nor at the end of any of the chonology branches. If we're referring to in-canon for the whole series, the answer is A Link Between Worlds, and if we're referring to in-canon for just the Wii, the answer is that there is none. I don't think it's a very good question either, but I disagree with the reason for closing it.

Comment: I got my answer. It is "Phantom Hourglass and Spirit Tracks". Thanks to Brian.

Comment: @Frank I meant to ask the next zelda game after skyward sword.

Comment: I'll vote to re-open, but be aware that we tend to frown on questions where very little effort is displayed.  We're not here to do your research for you, and these types of questions aren't going to be received very well.

Comment: @Frank okey, i'll try to be more clear and do more research before asking questions from now onwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were actually two Legend of Zelda games released between Twilight Princess and Skyward Sword: Phantom Hourglass and Spirit Tracks, both of which were released for the Nintendo DS.

The next original *Legend of Zelda* game that released after Skyward Sword was **A Link Between Worlds**, for the 3DS. See [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda#History) for a full chronology of releases.

Twilight Princess and Skyward Sword were the only two *Legend of Zelda* games released for the Wii, but there was also a spinoff game released for the Wii called [Link's Crossbow Training](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link%27s_Crossbow_Training). The [next *Legend of Zelda* game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda_(2015_video_game)) to release will be for the Wii U, and does not yet have an official name. There was also a crossover with the Dynasty Warriors series which released for the Wii U, titled [Hyrule Warriors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyrule_Warriors), and several *Legend of Zelda* characters appear in the [Super Smash Bros games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Smash_Bros._for_Nintendo_3DS_and_Wii_U) for 3DS and Wii U.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, can you please explain why?

Comment: Wow, i didn't knew about "a Link between Worlds". Thanks again.